# How to check sshd log?

Tags: ssh

I have Ubuntu 9.10 installed with `sshd` and I can successfully connect to it using login and password. I have configured an `RSA` key login and now have "Server refused our key" as expected. Ok, now I want to check `sshd` log in order to figure out a problem. I have examined `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` and it have

```
SyslogFacility AUTH
LogLevel INFO
```

Ok. I'm looking at `/var/log/auth.log` and... it's empty O_O. Changing `Loglevel` to `VERBOSE` helps nothing - `auth.log` is still empty. Any hints how I can check `sshd` log?

Comment: Did you check your syslog configuration? I don't run Ubuntu, but it may redirect the AUTH facility to a different logfile. Maybe /var/log/messages ?

Comment: How to check a syslog configuration? Unfortunately, i'm not very good a linux :(.
`cat /var/log/messages | grep ssh` shows nothing :(.

Comment: You are correct. `/etc/syslog.conf` redirects AUTH to `/var/logauth.log`. Please write your answer so i can accept it :)

Comment: On my machine: The system logs are set in /etc/rsyslog.conf, which in turn includes /etc/rsyslog.d/*

The actual file setting the location of the logs is /etc/rsyslog.d/50-default.conf.

Comment: On my servers, sshd logs to /var/log/secure.  This is configured in /etc/rsyslog.conf, on the line beginning "authpriv.*"

Comment: authpriv?? How the heck were we supposed to know that had anything to do with sshd? :-)

Comment: (6 years later ...) I guess  /etc/ssh/sshd_config shows "SyslogFacility AUTHPRIV" but yeah that's a bit of a stretch!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If no one else is using the system at the moment you could do what i've done in such cases:

- stop sshd service (at least i've been able to do this while logged in via ssh)
- start sshd manually and add some -d options to get more verbose debug output. Unless you have something funky going on it should use the same keys and config it does when started properly

Comment: Stopping SSHD on a remote server is a really bad idea. This may solve the problem for some (or most) setups most of the time, but if ANYTHING goes wrong - your connection, power on either end, forgetfulness, etc - you're locked out of the box. Which is bad news.

Comment: Well, it should be noted that the only way you could start the service after manually stopping it would be to have some other kind of access to it, like another non-SSH remote connection, or you're sitting in front of it.

Comment: How does this answer the question? I landed here from a web search expecting to learn how to check the SSHD log files, not what worked for you for some problem... Damn I wish readers on the Stack Exchange network would actually read and answer the question at hand, and not the question they want it to be....

Comment: You can start another sshd on another port. Connect to that one. Then stop the main sshd and start a new one on port 22. If anything fails, reboot the box using your DRAC or cloud management. You should have sshd starting on boot right? No worries.

Comment: @BrunoBronosky the second backup one can be configured as an onion service.

Comment: or just start a new instance on different port

Comment: Nowadays many VPS providers provide SSH console right within their control panel. So It's less likely you are locked out of the box.

Comment: I logged in just to downvote this answer. It's appalling and reflects poorly on ServerFault that this is considered a valid confirmed answer.

Comment: @JoelESalas The community doesn't decide which answers are accepted.

Comment: Stop using this solution!. Except you want to ruin your lifes. 
Use the answers below instead.

Comment: This is such a dangerously bad solution.

Comment: SSHD is not even possible to run interactive

Comment: @Sudowned Will connection not be closed when `sshd` stops? You seem to imply this by your comment.

Comment: @user145545 - Welcome to StackExchange, where non-answers are sacrosanct if they have a magic green checkmark.  And if you dare mention this obvious failure in Meta, you'll be downvoted and harassed by the dogmatic devs and mods.   Note also the vote sorting bug, where this non-answer comes _above_ the actual answer below which itself has _AN ORDER OF MAGNITUDE_ more votes.  SE is **horrible** and always will be in this regard because they don't care about accuracy or correctness.

Comment: Be warned if you are using cloud services. I just locked myself out of my Azure machine. As soon as I stopped `sshd` service, all established connections dropped

Comment: Make sure you have a spare ssh connection to the box in case something goes wrong. But you normally are save and can restart a sshd without affecting existing connections (contrary to what people claimed here.) This is the only option in a remote headless system.

Answer (score 263):

*Creating an answer based on the comments above, credit to @Prof. Moriarty and @Eye of Hell*

SSH auth failures are logged here `/var/log/auth.log`

The following should give you only ssh related log lines:

```
grep 'sshd' /var/log/auth.log
```

To be on the safe side, get the last few hundred lines and then search (because if the log file is too large, grep on the whole file would consume more system resources, not to mention will take longer to run)

View sshd entries in the last 500 lines of the log:

```
tail -n 500 /var/log/auth.log | grep 'sshd'
```

or to follow the log output as you test:

```
tail -f -n 500 /var/log/auth.log | grep 'sshd'
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit. That was an error on my part, should've been tail in the first place (not less). Like I say in the text - "get the last few hundred lines and then search"

Comment: This answer. Other answer with green arrow is bogus. Change arrow.

Comment: Why not use `tail -f ...` to monitor it in real time? Would this be an issue with larger log files?

Comment: `less +F ...` will 'tail' in real time, and it's much more powerful than tail

Comment: If your log is spammed with `Connection closed by 127.0.0.1 [preauth]`, remember that your nagios may be doing just his job every 5 minutes...

Comment: And `lnav` is even better than less/tail

Comment: P.s.: if your server is a Red Hat (as CentOS), the path of sshd/login records log is /var/log/secure (check /var/log folder for the log files of specific dates too). See this answer: https://serverfault.com/questions/465833/where-is-the-sshd-log-file-on-red-hat-linux-stored

Comment: The question must have been edited, because it specifically says auth.log is empty, so this answer wouldn't apply. I came here trying to find the alternative location for auth.log. Thanks @BrianHellekin.

Comment: less +F is nice, but doesn't let me add a few carriage returns to create some visual space after previous output.  Also, no such directory as /var/log/secure on my Suse system, no such file "auth.log", and sshd_config is totally commented out. Suse must do things differently from RH and Ubuntu flavors.

Answer (score 58):

The modern way to view logs:

1. **All** messages about `sshd`:
   `journalctl -t sshd`
   or
   `journalctl -u ssh` where `-u == unit`
2. Messages about `sshd` from the last boot:
   `journalctl -t sshd -b0`
3. Messages about `sshd` from the last boot in the reverse order:
   `journalctl -t sshd -b0 -r`

Comment: Yep !!! Also journalctl -u ssh, where u = unit . With this syntax you can use for any systemd unit

Comment: I tried `-u sshd` and it didn't work, but `-u ssh` works, thanks!

Comment: I tested `-u ssh` ( 32 seconds  ) vs `-t sshd` ( 10 seconds ) on my home server. It appeared that `-t sshd` is 3 times faster.

Answer (score 50):

If you can try the failing connection again easily, one way easy way is to start an SSH server on a free port such as `2222`:

```
/usr/sbin/sshd -d -p 2222
```

and then retry the connection with:

```
ssh -p 2222 user@host
```

By using the different port `-p 2222`, we don't have to stop the main SSH server, which could lock us out.

See also: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/55481/32558

Comment: One of the best options, specially if you only have SSH access to a server. Debugging the connection by stopping the ssh server will drop you out of session. Just start a new ssh daemon on a different port and test the login using that port.

Comment: @AttilaAntal Small correction: stopping sshd will not kill active ssh sessions. This method is a good precaution in case something goes wrong, but in theory you can easily stop and then restart sshd over ssh.

Comment: @ParkerKemp it doesn't kill the connection, and if everything is working as expected, you should be able to continue using it after after restarting the daemon. The problem, however, will be if for some reason the Daemon couldn't start. Then the active session will drop.

Comment: use sudo and absolute path if you can not create host key

Answer (score 9):

If you want to see all log messages about sshd, run this:

```
grep -rsh sshd /var/log |sort
```

Comment: Logs will start with entries like `Mar 14 19:52:04` which exclude the year and are not easily sorted (though you may get lucky with `sort --month-sort` assuming you don't go over a boundary between years).  The log files themselves are already sorted, so you just have to scan them in the right order.  Also, the recursive `grep -r` call will be really slow on systems with large logs.  There's no reason to additionally scan things like your HTTPD logs.

Comment: thx, i didn't know what flavor i was on, but this helped me find `/var/log/secure` (i actually ended up changing the command to `grep -Rsl sshd /var/log` but +1 for getting my thinking cap to appear).

Comment: tail -5000f /var/log/messages|grep -i sshd

Answer (score 5):

You can use the following command to see the logs from SSH:

```
tail -f /var/log/auth.log
```

Comment: Welcome to ServerFault.  Did you read the question?  He isn't getting data in that file.  `tail`ing it useless if it doesn't have any data in it.

Comment: @chicks That's funny. Answer with most votes is almost the same like this..

Answer (score 3):

You might find the following commands useful as well:

```
sudo journalctl --system --follow
sudo journalctl --system --follow | grep -i ssh
```

Comment: You can also use `sudo journalctl --system --follow -u ssh.service` to monitor only `ssh` unit.

Answer (score 1):

Not for topicstarter, but for another opensuse tumbleweed users:

```
systemctl status sshd.service
journalctl -xeu sshd.service
```

The first gives you the status and time of fault:

```
 sshd.service - OpenSSH Daemon
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/sshd.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2022-06-15 19:15:20 MSK; 10min ago
```

The second may give you more details, something like:

```
Jun 15 19:15:19 localhost.localdomain sshd[2124]: 
/etc/ssh/sshd_config.d/sshd.conf line 121: Directive 'usepam' is not allowed within a Match block
```

Answer (score -2):

In CentOS 7. I have found out SSH logs over here:

```
$ tail /var/log/audit/audit.log
```

Comment: In default installation, `/var/log/audit/audit.log` stores *SELinux* logs in CentOS, not `sshd`. Source: https://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/SELinux#Troubleshooting_SELinux