# MySQL cannot connect via SSH tunnel -- Connection refused

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, ssh

I am trying to connect to MySQL from my MySQL GUI (Sequel Pro if it matters) using SSH tunnel. However, I keep getting the following error (mysql.log):

> [Note] Aborted connection 98 to db: 'example' user: 'example_user' host: 'localhost' (Got an error reading communication packets)

My connection settings look like the following:

- SSH host: example.com
- SSH port: 22
- SSH user: example_user
- SSH pass: ********
- DB host: 127.0.0.1
- DB user: example_user
- DB password: *******
- DB name: example
- DB port: 3306

I can connect to SSH with no problems. I can also connect to MySQL from inside SSH (using `mysql -u example_user -p -h 127.0.0.1`)

However, tunneling is not working. I have `AllowTcpForwarding yes` in sshd_config. MySQL config has `bind-address = 127.0.0.1`.

I am using 16.04 LTS and MySQL Community Edition in my server.

What am I doing wrong? This is the first time I am seeing this issue.

Comment: What are you using to create the SSH tunnel?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What causes the 'Connection Refused' message?](http://serverfault.com/questions/725262/what-causes-the-connection-refused-message)

Comment: I am using the Sequel Pro client. That client currently connects to 3 different remote hosts via SSH tunnel. This is the only host where this doesn't work, so I my guess is it is a problem in the host machine.

Comment: @istheEnglishway MySQL is listening on 127.0.0.1:3306. I have UFW disabled and iptables is empty with default ACCEPT. One thing that I am having doubts here is the SSH server used in Ubuntu. It is called `OpenBSD Secure Shell server`. I have always used OpenSSH server and never had a single issue with it. Can this server not have a TCP forwarding feature? I am asking this because `AllowTcpForwarding` option did not exist in sshd_config. I added it myself with no luck

Comment: Nevermind, OpenBSD Secure Shell is the long name for OpenSSH.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create several tunnels via command on workstation by example:

```
ssh -L 10080:127.0.0.1:80 -L 10006:127.0.0.1:3306 user@server
```

There are: `127.0.0.1` - ip-address tunnel's destination to connect from server, `80` and `3306` destination ports, `10080` and `10006` - local workstation's ports.
This will allow you to connect to MySql server and to Http server via server's localhost interface.
Run command `mysql -p -u db_user -P 10006 -h 127.0.0.1 database_name` on workstation to connect to MySql server. You can connect to PhpMyAdmin web interface, which is allowed only from 127.0.0.1. To do it simply write address `http://127.0.0.1:10080` in your browser.

Comment: For some reason tunelling like that actually works but tunelling through my mysql application doesn't work, which is very weird IMO.

Comment: @Gasim Try to use "Standard connection" to host 127.0.0.1 and port 10006.

Comment: Also check how well will a long file (500Mb) be copied from server to workstation via scp command?

Comment: staandard connection worked. I just didn't want to have a separate tunnel open when my app can do it. I'm going to investigate to see what can cause this problem.

Comment: I think you can use sshd log on the server as described at    http://serverfault.com/questions/130482/how-to-check-sshd-log

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, and per this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12568665/4146923), the solution was removing the 'any' user.

It seems that MySQL sees a difference between a user connecting via localhost and 127.0.0.1, which is part of the issue if I understand it correctly.

Comment: MySQL's authentication layer is not going to cause a connection refused message.